# Reading a Soil Size Distribution Diagram

Tags: soil

I have the *Soil Size Distribution Diagram* shown below from a source that does not specify the meaning of the labels A1=60, A2=50, and A3=50. I understand that it is data for three different samples, but what do the numbers (60, 50, 50) indicates?

[image]

The diagram is constructed following a standard protocol where soil is collected, washed, dried, and sieved.

If anyone can shed some light on the meaning of the labels A1=60, A2=50, and A3=50, it would be most helpful.

Comment: Perhaps you should give the source, people may have more info from that

Comment: It is from an ISO standard 13.060.30 (sewage water disposal and treatment https://www.iso.org/ics/13.060.30/x/). Not many details are included in the text; my guess is that it is some standard way of labeling curves that I'm not familiar with.